# Eliminar focus de un boton

Tags: java, java-swing

Al abrir un jframe con botones por defecto el focus se pone en uno de ellos, me gustaria que ningun boton lo tenga

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes eliminarlo con [`setFocusPainted(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted-boolean-). Entonces harías algo como esto:

```
button.setFocusable(false);
```

Espero te funcione.